# Testing transactions on action console simulator gives USER_ACTION_REQUIRED response on Transaction Check action

Tags: actions-on-google

I am creating an app using actions that uses transactions. I am creating this app for use in the US but developing and testing it in India where Transactions aren't supported yet so Transaction Check action is giving me: `REGION_NOT_SUPPORTED` response(when using assistant from mobile device with same dev account).

And when using simulator on action console with different location,  Transaction Check action is giving: `USER_ACTION_REQUIRED` response. Is there a work around? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setup proper Google Pay payment profile with a valid card and address.